# Cannot play local WMV in silverlight MediaElement

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

I am trying to play a video in WMV format in a silverlight MediaElement.

```
<StackPanel>
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="Bounce.wmv" 
         Width="300" Height="300" AutoPlay="True" />
  </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

This does nothing.. but if I change the source attribute to point to some WMV out on the web it works.

What am I doing wrong? I have the the movie in the same directory as the MainPage.xaml

Comment: What do you mean by "Local"?  Is this wmv packaged into the XAP?

Comment: Is it actually alongside the .xap, as a .wmv? Or is it just on the local computer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would depend on what page you are calling it from. If you are calling from a different XAML page that is in a sub-directory, like Views, you'll need to change the `Source` to a relative path. Give `Source="\Bounce.wmv"` and `Source="..\Bounce.wmv"` a try, depending on the folder structure you are in when calling it.